# “Undefined symbol _main” when linking OpenMP on macOS Catalina

Tags: c++, macos, gcc, openmp, macos-catalina

I just installed OpenMP by running

```
$ brew install gcc
```

Than I ran my code using

```
$ gcc-10 -o task -fopenmp task.c
```

However I got the error message:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_main", referenced from:
     implicit entry/start for main executable
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

My code is:

```
#include <omp.h>
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: Where is your `main` function?

Comment: Could I suggest you to first create a basic "Hello World" to be sure that the compiler is properly setup, then OpenMP can be the next challenge.

Comment: Thanks for answering me. It happens even if I add the main. I wrote just the first line to underline that it happens even with the simplest code possible. Just including that library.

Comment: Your "simplest code possible" wouldn't compile, ever. And is this a C question, or a C++ question?

Comment: Please post the code that fails, not some stripped down form of it that would obviously fail.

Comment: Perfect guys, I will riformulate the question posting all the code. thank you

Comment: You can edit your existing questions to add code or further details. There is no need to post another one.

Comment: Thank you all guys. I solved this problem replacing gcc with g++. as you can see in another of my post now I have to build a makefile and this is my currently problem /:

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem replacing gcc with g++